# ggplot2 plot data: Error in xy.coords 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I currently have to learn about Rstudio and I am a bloody beginner in it. My plan was to create multiple plots and merge them together, but I already get an error code I cant solve right at the beginning.

I started like this:

```
 Data_v_S<- Data_Kinetik[1:4,2]
 Data_v_S$"[NAD+]  0,1867 mmol/L"<- Data_Kinetik[1:4,6]
 Data_v_S$"[NAD+]  0,2667 mmol/L"<- Data_Kinetik[5:8,6]
 Data_v_S$"[NAD+]  0,4667 mmol/L"<- Data_Kinetik[9:12,6]
 Data_v_S$"[NAD+]  1,8667 mmol/L"<- Data_Kinetik[13:16,6]

x <- Data_v_S$`[EtOH] mmol/L`
y1 <- Data_v_S$`[NAD+]  0,1867 mmol/L`

plot(x,y1,col="red",type = "b",ylab = "[DE/min]",xlab = "[EtOH] mmol/L")
```

but I always get the error:

```
    Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

My data:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  `[EtOH] mmol/L` `[NAD+]  0,1867 mmol~ `[NAD+]  0,2667 mmol~ `[NAD+]  0,4667 mmol~ `[NAD+]  1,8667 mmol~
            <dbl>                 <dbl>                 <dbl>                 <dbl>                 <dbl>
1            2                    0.225                 0.242                 0.337                 0.473
2            1                    0.180                 0.210                 0.284                 0.409
3            0.5                  0.138                 0.167                 0.232                 0.347
4            0.25                 0.1                   0.113                 0.162                 0.255
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image: has to be like this excel]

Comment: I get no error. I'm using `structure(list(\`[EtOH] mmol/L\` = c(2, 1, 0.5, 0.25), \`[NAD+]  0,1867 mmol/L\` = c(0.225, 0.18, 0.138, 0.1), \`[NAD+]  0,2667 mmol/L\` = c(0.242, 0.21, 0.167, 0.113), \`[NAD+]  0,4667 mmol/L\` = c(0.337, 0.284, 0.232, 0.162), \`[NAD+]  1,8667 mmol/L\` = c(0.473, 0.409, 0.347, 0.255)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))` which seems right, but no error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get that error with `plot(x, y1, ...)`, but I can reproduce that style of plot using `ggplot2`. The reason I recommend `ggplot2` over base plots here is that while `plot(.); lines(.); lines(.); lines(.);` will get you what you're trying to do, it can at times be prone to user-error (typos, different glitches in the data, etc), and `ggplot2` tends to protect against many of these mistakes.

The first step is to reshape the data, since `ggplot2` really benefits from having it in a "long" format. For instance, your data is currently:

```r
Data_v_S
#   [EtOH] mmol/L [NAD+]  0,1867 mmol/L [NAD+]  0,2667 mmol/L [NAD+]  0,4667 mmol/L [NAD+]  1,8667 mmol/L
# 1          2.00                 0.225                 0.242                 0.337                 0.473
# 2          1.00                 0.180                 0.210                 0.284                 0.409
# 3          0.50                 0.138                 0.167                 0.232                 0.347
# 4          0.25                 0.100                 0.113                 0.162                 0.255
```

and a "long" format of this is something like:

```r
long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(Data_v_S, -`[EtOH] mmol/L`)
# # A tibble: 16 x 3
#    `[EtOH] mmol/L` name                  value
#              <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
#  1            2    [NAD+]  0,1867 mmol/L 0.225
#  2            2    [NAD+]  0,2667 mmol/L 0.242
#  3            2    [NAD+]  0,4667 mmol/L 0.337
#  4            2    [NAD+]  1,8667 mmol/L 0.473
#  5            1    [NAD+]  0,1867 mmol/L 0.18 
#  6            1    [NAD+]  0,2667 mmol/L 0.21 
#  7            1    [NAD+]  0,4667 mmol/L 0.284
#  8            1    [NAD+]  1,8667 mmol/L 0.409
#  9            0.5  [NAD+]  0,1867 mmol/L 0.138
# 10            0.5  [NAD+]  0,2667 mmol/L 0.167
# 11            0.5  [NAD+]  0,4667 mmol/L 0.232
# 12            0.5  [NAD+]  1,8667 mmol/L 0.347
# 13            0.25 [NAD+]  0,1867 mmol/L 0.1  
# 14            0.25 [NAD+]  0,2667 mmol/L 0.113
# 15            0.25 [NAD+]  0,4667 mmol/L 0.162
# 16            0.25 [NAD+]  1,8667 mmol/L 0.255
```

With this, we can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long, aes(`[EtOH] mmol/L`, value, group = name, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = NULL) +
  labs(y = expression("Steigung [" * Delta * "E/min]"))
```

[image: basic ggplot with updated labels and grouped lined]

---

Data:

```r
Data_v_S <- structure(list(`[EtOH] mmol/L` = c(2, 1, 0.5, 0.25), `[NAD+]  0,1867 mmol/L` = c(0.225, 0.18, 0.138, 0.1), `[NAD+]  0,2667 mmol/L` = c(0.242, 0.21, 0.167, 0.113), `[NAD+]  0,4667 mmol/L` = c(0.337, 0.284, 0.232, 0.162), `[NAD+]  1,8667 mmol/L` = c(0.473, 0.409, 0.347, 0.255)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```